# Get parent wise sub category upto n-level and in arranged format in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

My database table name is `tbl_services`. And i have Model with name `Services.php` in App folder. i am trying to get all sub category on the basis of parent category and all sub-sub category of sub category basis here is how my table looks like:

[image]

Now after arrangement in Laravel it should look like this:

```
Animal
   Tiger
      White Tiger
Birds
   Pegion
```

This just an example. I would like to go **`upto n-level`**. Is there any solution or any easy way of doing this in Laravel 5.2

Thank you!

Comment: [Modified Preorder Tree Traversal](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) is probably what you want for something like this

Comment: No i dont have left and rigts

Comment: you can add them or bog down the system with recursion

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, Can you please suggest any example? I am trying to search online, but not getting the results.